# Where can I see dolphins in central Europe, near Poland?

Tags: nature-and-wildlife, poland, central-europe

I live in Poland and I would like to take my children to some place where we can see dolphins. There is no such place in Poland so I would like to know where they are near south-western Poland (especially in Germany or Czech Republic) and whether they are worth to visit (considering that it can be quite long journey from Poland).

Of course I think about some kind of ZOO, not a wild nature

Comment: Finally, 3 years after asking this question, we have visited dolphinarium in Klaipeda (Lithuania). Here http://www.psur.pl/a.aspx?id=302 is our post about it (with photos and movie, but text is in polish).

Comment: Keeping dolphins in captivity is very cruel! Don't visit dolphinariums. Don't teach your kids that cruelty towards animals is acceptable.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Germany, the Zoos of [Nürnberg](http://www.tiergarten.nuernberg.de/v04/Delphinarium.19.0.html) and [Duisburg](http://www.zoo-duisburg.de/hoehepunkte-des-zoo-duisburg/rwe-delfinarium/haltung-und-praesentation.html) have Dolphin exhibits/shows (another one in [Münster] will be shut down this fall). The one in Nürnberg is probably closest to you and also seems to be the largest. But note that there's considerable controversity about whether keeping Dolphins in indoor pools constitutes animal abuse, given that even the largest pools are tiny in comparison with their natural movement habits.

Comment: Thanks for the specific locations! Nurnberg is quite close to me, I can even try to travel there and get back home during one day (long day).

Answer (score 12):

**Would you believe, Wikipedia has a [list of dolphinariums](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_dolphinariums)!**

I won't list them all, but basically there are several in Germany (Allwetter Zoo Münster, Duisburg Zoo, Tiergarten Nürnberg) and Lithuania is also pretty close, depending where in Poland you are (Lithuanian Sea Museum, Klaipėda) - but I'll leave it to you to check out the list.

Answer (score 5):

Lithuanian Dolphinarium is closed for reconstruction at the moment. And the Dolphins are in Greece. But I've heard that soon it will be open again.
http://www.muziejus.lt/en/index.html
http://cetabase.blogspot.ru/2010/10/oct-20th-2010-dolphins-move-from.html